# difference between directly mentioning property name and mentioning property using PATH keyword in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

What is the difference between mentioning the property name in Binding and using the property name with the "Path" in WPF? I find it a lot of places/people use it in a mixed manner.

```
<TextBox Text = {Binding Firstname}\>
```

vs

```
<TextBox Text = {Binding Path = Firstname }\>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean. Perhaps you can put in some code listing.

Comment: @Aron: Thank you for asking, I have written the code lines, don't know why it is not appearing here. Anyway, it looks like duplicate of the other poster here.

Comment: @Divine, you can also find more information on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413(v=vs.110).aspx) site in the _Implicit Path_ section